# running two different programming language one after another automatically

Tags: java, c++, shell

I have two seperate codes one is written in c++ and the other is in java. Now what I want to do is ,First I want to run c++ code, and then I want to give the output file of this program  to the second program, writen in java, as an input. I need to do this fully automatically. Is there a possible way to do this ?

I mean, 
I'll type a single command into terminal and what I`ve explained above will occur.

Do I need to write a shell script for that ?

Comment: By the way, I work on ubuntu 12.04 LTS but It would be better what I`ll do support cross platform.

Comment: You can use `Java Native Invocation`, but shell script would be much easier.

Comment: JNI is one option but I never liked it.

Comment: @Everv0id, thanks for the reply, I dont have any shell script experience, does  it be so hard for me ?

Comment: Why JNI? Does it really matter which programming languages you are using, which is first or second? All you need to have is 2 executables ready and then use shell scripting, "pipe" forward the output from one program to other..

Comment: No, it's not hard. Actually, you can write only one line using *stream redirection*.

Comment: @user1757052 I think a shell script is the right solution.

Comment: Anyone remembers, how ls & sed work together. Use pipe simple.

ls -l | sed -e "s/[aeio]/u/g"

Comment: @user1757052, my answer helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it really matter which programming languages you are using, which is first or second? All you need to have is 2 executable ready and then use shell scripting, use "pipe" to forward the output from one program to other..

e.g. `ls -l | sed -e "s/[aeio]/u/g"`

Update:

`cppprogram1 | java program2 cppprogram1.txt`

cppprogram1.txt is output file generated by cppprogram1.

Comment: since I dont have any experience with shell, I have to ask this, the line of code provided by you above does not do that  what I want right? It is just an example

Comment: No ofcourse not, this is an example how you can use pipe. "|"

Comment: Why such troubles? At least, Java allows to use `<` and `>` operators to redirect `System.in` and `System.out`. I suppose `cin` and `cout` in c++ can be used similar way.

Comment: @Everv0id, You haven't understood what OP is asking!

Comment: @user1 sorry, you are correct. Pipes solve problem completely.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your situation. If you just want to throw the output of a executable, use pipe. The C++ binary would output to stdout, and the java file would read from stdin. If you need something more sophisticated, you probably need to use one of those serialization libraries like Thrift.